# Possible bug in wcsrtombs_s

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, unicode, visual-studio-2017

Have I found a bug in `wcsrtombs_s` in which it fails to return to the caller? The `_TRUNCATE` macro when supplied as the `count` argument is supposed to prevent a buffer overrun when the size of the destination string is known (an array reference) while filling the `mbstr` parameter with as many characters as it can hold *including* the null terminator. I have targeted this to a 64-bit build in VS 2017. Note that `vcruntime.h` defines `size_t` as a 64-bit unsigned integer rather than as a 32-bit unsigned integer (possibly a clue?). As an experiment, I have explicitly substituted respectively `UINT32_MAX` and `UINT64_MAX` with no change in the results (recall that each of those is all bits set just like -1 and `_TRUNCATE`, but they differ per size). The overload in question per the Microsoft docs (found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcsrtombs-s?view=msvc-160) ) is as follows:

```
template <size_t size>
errno_t wcsrtombs_s(
   size_t *pReturnValue,
   char (&mbstr)[size],
   const wchar_t **wcstr,
   sizeof count,
   mbstate_t *mbstate
); // C++ only
```

My second invocation of `wcsrtombs_s` anticipates the return value `STRUNCATE` but unfortunately never gets that far:

```
    const wchar_t wcstr[32] = L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char mbstr[16] = { 0 };
    size_t ret_val = 0;
    mbstate_t mbstate = { 0 };
    wchar_t *pws = wcstr;
    // this code returns to the caller
    errno_t ret_code = wcsrtombs_s(&ret_val, mbstr, &pws, 15, &mbstate);

    *mbstr = 0;
    mbstate = { 0 };
    ret_val = 0;

    // this code fails to return to the caller!
    ret_code = wcsrtombs_s(&ret_val, mbstr, &pws, _TRUNCATE, &mbstate);
```

Comment: Any potential bugs would be in a specific implementation. From the `_s` suffix I assume you're using MSVC and its implementation?

Comment: Yes indeed, per *"VS 2017"* in my original post

Comment: Please specify the incorrect order of the args, thanks

Comment: No I misread, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `sizeof count` is their docs doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: MS may have intended size_t, dunno ...

Comment: Your code runs fine for me (in VS2019), but note that `wcsrtombs_s()` changes `pws` so you should reset it before the second call

Comment: It seems an issue in vs2017, I have post the issue to DC. You could follow this thread:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-issue-of-wcsrtombs-s-in-the-visual-studio-2017/1481532?from=email